# ST_Within to find containing polygon (but same table?)

Tags: qgis, postgis, within

I have nested polygons and would like to set a parent_zone field to describe the polygon it is within. There will only ever be one to choose from (ensured by the 'type' filter).

I am trying:

```
UPDATE network.zones
SET parent_zone = network.zones.id
FROM network.zones 
WHERE network.zones.type = 'PON' AND ST_Within(network.zones.geom, network.zones.geom)
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR:  table name "zones" specified more than once
SQL state: 42712
```

Is this just very bad practise, and should I create a table for each polygon 'type' instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give an alias to tables:

```sql
UPDATE network.zones c
SET parent_zone = p.id
FROM network.zones p
WHERE p.type = 'PON' AND ST_Within(c.geom, p.geom)
```

Comment: Thank you that works :)